# Get data from Horizontal Table to Vertical Table Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a source table like:

```
     A             B         C           D
     -----------------------------------------------------
1    Area          Monday    Tuesday     Wednesday
     -----------------------------------------------------
2    Area1         2         1           3
3    Area2         3         2           4
```

I have a lot of data like the table above. Then I have the following table that need to be filled:

```
     F             G            H
     -----------------------------------------
1    Area          Day          Rate
     -----------------------------------------
2    Area2         Wednesday    4
3    Area1         Monday       2
```

How Can I do that to fill the value under rate column with formula?
Thank you.

Comment: You Can use Transpose methodology here, that will work for you

Comment: Are you trying to transform the entire table, or just using it as a lookup for a subset of the data?

Comment: Your output is not making sense, is there a typo. For Area 2 Wednesday the rate should be 4. Can you confirm that

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, yes... Apologize, I just edit it. Thanks for it.

Comment: @DS_London, lookup from the horizontal table. and lookup value is on vertical table

Comment: @Haminteu just posted in answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$A$3,FILTER($B$2:$D$3,G2=$B$1:$D$1))
```

---

And fill down!

---

You can also use a <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper function to spill the array so no need to fill down

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=MAP(F2:F3,G2:G3,LAMBDA(x,y,XLOOKUP(x,A2:A3,FILTER(B2:D3,y=B1:D1))))
```

---

Perhaps if you are not using `MS365` then

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$3,MATCH(F2,$A$2:$A$3,0),MATCH(G2,$B$1:$D$1,0))
```

---

Or, since the `Rate` are numerics we can use <kbd>SUMPRODUCT( )</kbd> or <kbd>SUM( )</kbd> based on ones excel version as well

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=SUM((F2=$A$2:$A$3)*(G2=$B$1:$D$1)*$B$2:$D$3)
```

---

Comment: I use the INDEX function and it works! Thanks a lot mate!!!

Comment: @Haminteu sounds good, you made it work out =)